# Don't get response calling Amazon api gateway service using Ajax methods using jQuery version > 1.9

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a tool in Asp.NET MVC4(VS 2013. By default I have used Microsoft internet application and developed the tool, but my most of the work includes client side jQuery, HTML and ajax methods. I am using jQuery version 1.8.2 (by default it was included) and my ajax call is working fine as find below:

AJAX Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var controllersDDL = $('#Controllers');
             $.ajax({

                url: 'url',//here amazon api gateway url
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    controllersDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: -1, text: 'Select Controller' }));
$(data).each(function (index, item) {
controllersDDL.append($('<option/>', { text: item.name }));

});
}
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label style="margin-right:50px"> Controller </label>

                            <select style="width:150px;" id="Controllers"></select>


                    </div>
```

Same code is working for Jquery 1.8.2 but once I upgrade in jQuery version above 1.9 its not working.
I am getting 403 Result in debugger tool for these POST requests.Even i tried in working visual studio project having Jquery 1.10.2 but getting same result.No success.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure halfer..Thanks.